# Несколько разных слайдеров на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5

### Помогите реализовать код так чтобы можно было вставлять несколько слайдеров на странице Сейчас код применяется ко всем слайдерам сразу Спасибо

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.img').click(function() {
    var image = $(this).attr('data-img');
    $('#image').attr('src', image);
  });

  $(".slider-gallery-block-item").click(function() {
    $(".slider-gallery-block-item").removeClass('active-opacity');
    $(this).addClass('active-opacity');
  });
  var slideCount = $('.slider-gallery-block-item').length;
  var slideWidth = $('.slider-gallery-block-item').width();
  var slideHeight = $('.slider-gallery-block-item').height();
  var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;

  function moveLeft() {
    $('.slider-gallery-block').animate({
      left: +slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('.slider-gallery-block-item:last-child').prependTo('.slider-gallery-block');
      $('.slider-gallery-block').css('left', '');
    });
  };

  function moveRight() {
    $('.slider-gallery-block').animate({
      left: -slideWidth
    }, 200, function() {
      $('.slider-gallery-block-item:first-child').appendTo('.slider-gallery-block');
      $('.slider-gallery-block').css('left', '');

    });
  };

  $('.nav-arrow-up').click(function() {
    moveLeft();
    var image = $('.img').attr('data-img');
    $('#image').attr('src', image);
  });

  $('.nav-arrow-down').click(function() {
    moveRight();
    var image = $('.img').attr('data-img');
    $('#image').attr('src', image);
  });
  var imgPopup = $('.img_popup');
  var imgPopupFull = $('.img_popup_full');
  var imgCont = $('.nav-zoom img');
  var popupImage = $('.img_popup img');
  var closeBtn = $('.close_btn');
  imgCont.on('click', function() {
    var img_src = $('.slider-gallery-img').children('img').attr('src');
    imgPopupFull.children('img').attr('src', img_src);
    imgPopup.addClass('opened');
  });
  $(imgPopup, closeBtn).on('click', function() {
    imgPopup.removeClass('opened');
    imgPopupFull.children('img').attr('src', '');
  });
  popupImage.on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
*,
::before,
::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

:focus {
  outline: none
}

:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0
}

:focus::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0
}

:focus:-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0
}

:focus:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0
}

p,
dd,
dl,
figure,
blockquote {
  margin: 0
}

blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none
}

ul,
ol {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}

th {
  font-weight: inherit
}

h1 {
  font-size: calc(24px + 16 * ((100vw - 320px) / 820))
}

h2 {
  font-size: calc(18px + 16 * ((100vw - 320px) / 820))
}

h3 {
  font-size: calc(18px + 12 * ((100vw - 320px) / 820))
}

h4 {
  font-size: calc(16px + 10 * ((100vw - 320px) / 820))
}

h5 {
  font-size: calc(16px + 8 * ((100vw - 320px) / 820))
}

h6 {
  font-size: calc(16px + 4 * ((100vw - 320px) / 820))
}

p {
  font-size: calc(14px + 4 * ((100vw - 320px) / 820))
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: inherit
}

audio,
video {
  display: block
}

img {
  display: block;
  border: none
}

iframe {
  border: none
}

pre,
code,
kbd,
samp {
  font-family: Consolas, Monaco;
  font-size: inherit
}

a,
a:hover,
a:focus,
a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease;
  transition: all .3s ease
}

abbr {
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: inherit
}

i,
em {
  font-style: inherit
}

dfn {
  font-style: inherit
}

mark {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: inherit
}

small {
  font-size: inherit
}

sub,
sup {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: 0
}

sub {
  bottom: -.25em
}

sup {
  top: -.5em
}

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  letter-spacing: inherit
}

button,
input {
  overflow: visible
}

button,
select {
  text-align: left;
  text-transform: none
}

button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit'] {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type='button']::-moz-focus-inner,
[type='reset']::-moz-focus-inner,
[type='submit']::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
  padding: 0
}

button:-moz-focusring,
[type='button']:-moz-focusring,
[type='reset']:-moz-focusring,
[type='submit']:-moz-focusring {
  outline: none
}

[type='number']::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type='number']::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto
}

[type='search']::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

[type='search'] {
  outline: none
}

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  font: inherit
}

fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none
}

legend {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  white-space: normal
}

select::-ms-expand {
  display: none
}

svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: currentColor
}

[hidden] {
  display: none
}

:disabled,
.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed
}

::-ms-clear {
  display: none
}

:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 100px #fff inset;
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px #fff inset;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: currentColor
}

::-moz-selection {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #004fe4
}

::selection {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #004fe4
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s
}

::-moz-placeholder {
  color: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s
}

:-moz-placeholder {
  color: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition: opacity .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: inherit;
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-transition: opacity .3s;
  transition: opacity .3s
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #ffffff99
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #000000cc;
  border-radius: 0
}

html {
  background: #2e2e2e;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.25;
  color: #000000cc;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-text-decoration-skip: objects;
  text-decoration-skip: objects;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto
}

.main__wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slider-gallery {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 312px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slider-gallery::after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-gallery-img {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.slider-gallery-block {
  padding-left: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider-gallery-img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-gallery-block-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 109px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  opacity: .5;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.slider-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 45px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 2fr 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  /* opacity: 0; */
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}

.nav-arrow {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.opacity {
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-arrow-up,
.nav-arrow-down {
  opacity: .2;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.nav-zoom img {
  opacity: .7;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.nav-zoom img:hover,
.nav-arrow-up:hover,
.nav-arrow-down:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
}

.nav-arrow img {
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav-zoom img {
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.active-opacity {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider__wrap {
  width: 630px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}

.container__img_holder {
  max-width: 280px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container__video_holder {
  max-width: 280px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container__img_holder img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 190px;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(50%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(50%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(50%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(50%);
  filter: grayscale(50%);
}

.container__web .container__img_holder {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.img_popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: none;
  z-index: 3;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.img_popup_full {
  position: relative;
}

.img_popup img {
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100px);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.close_btn {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100px);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100px);
}

.close_btn:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.close_btn:after,
.close_btn:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.close_btn:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close_btn:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.close_btn .bar:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.close_btn .bar:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(-2px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.opened {
  display: flex;
}

.closed {
  display: none;
}

.opened img,
.opened iframe,
.opened .close_btn {
  animation: animatepopup 1s ease-in-out .8s;
  -webkit-animation: animatepopup .3s ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes animatepopup {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    -o-transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .slider-gallery-block {
    display: none;
  }
  .slider__wrap {
    width: 445px;
  }
  .slider-gallery {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .slider-gallery-block {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: max-content;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    grid-column-gap: 20px;
  }
  .slider-gallery {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 105px;
    grid-row-gap: 1em;
  }
  .slider__wrap {
    width: auto;
  }
  .slider-gallery-block-item {
    justify-self: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
  }
  .slider-nav {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: none;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .nav-arrow-up {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
  .nav-zoom img {
    width: 25px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  .nav-arrow {
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav-arrow-up,
  .nav-arrow-down {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .nav-arrow-up img {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  .nav-arrow-down img {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}

@media (max-width: 430px) {
  .slider-gallery {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 94px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 350px) {
  .slider-gallery {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 87px;
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="" />
  <title></title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main__wrapper">
    <div class="container">


      <div class="slider__wrap" id="slider1">
        <div class="slider-gallery">
          <div class="slider-gallery-img">
            <img id="image" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/1.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="slider-nav">
              <div class="nav-zoom">
                <img src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/icons/zoom.svg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="nav-arrow">
                <div class="nav-arrow-up next slider-link">
                  <img src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/icons/arrow-up.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="nav-arrow-down prev slider-link">
                  <img src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/icons/arrow-down.svg" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="slider-gallery-block">
            <div class="slider-gallery-block-item active-opacity">
              <img class="img" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/1.jpg" alt="" data-img="http://test.andygroove.com/image/1.jpg" />
            </div>

            <div class="slider-gallery-block-item">
              <img class="img" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/2.jpg" alt="" data-img="http://test.andygroove.com/image/2.jpg" />
            </div>

            <div class="slider-gallery-block-item">
              <img class="img" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/3.jpg" alt="" data-img="http://test.andygroove.com/image/3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slider-gallery-block-item">
              <img class="img" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/4.jpg" alt="" data-img="http://test.andygroove.com/image/4.jpg" />
            </div>

            <div class="slider-gallery-block-item">
              <img class="img" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/5.jpg" alt="" data-img="http://test.andygroove.com/image/5.jpg" />
            </div>

            <div class="slider-gallery-block-item">
              <img class="img" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/6.jpg" alt="" data-img="http://test.andygroove.com/image/6.jpg" />
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="img_popup">
          <div class="img_popup_full"><img src="" alt="Popup Image">
            <div class="close_btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="slider__wrap" id="slider2">
        <div class="slider-gallery">
          <div class="slider-gallery-img">
            <img id="image" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/1.jpg" alt="" />
            <div class="slider-nav">
              <div class="nav-zoom">
                <img src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/icons/zoom.svg" alt="">
              </div>
              <div class="nav-arrow">
                <div class="nav-arrow-up next slider-link">
                  <img src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/icons/arrow-up.svg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="nav-arrow-down prev slider-link">
                  <img src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/icons/arrow-down.svg" alt="">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="slider-gallery-block">
            <div class="slider-gallery-block-item active-opacity">
              <img class="img" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/1.jpg" alt="" data-img="http://test.andygroove.com/image/1.jpg" />
            </div>

            <div class="slider-gallery-block-item">
              <img class="img" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/2.jpg" alt="" data-img="http://test.andygroove.com/image/2.jpg" />
            </div>

            <div class="slider-gallery-block-item">
              <img class="img" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/3.jpg" alt="" data-img="http://test.andygroove.com/image/3.jpg" />
            </div>
            <div class="slider-gallery-block-item">
              <img class="img" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/4.jpg" alt="" data-img="http://test.andygroove.com/image/4.jpg" />
            </div>

            <div class="slider-gallery-block-item">
              <img class="img" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/5.jpg" alt="" data-img="http://test.andygroove.com/image/5.jpg" />
            </div>

            <div class="slider-gallery-block-item">
              <img class="img" src="http://test.andygroove.com/image/6.jpg" alt="" data-img="http://test.andygroove.com/image/6.jpg" />
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="img_popup">
          <div class="img_popup_full"><img src="" alt="Popup Image">
            <div class="close_btn"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>



    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: _чтобы можно было вставлять несколько слайдеров на странице_ - у вас и так несколько их на странице... Что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: они работают некоректно